# Call get API with params

Tags: node.js, api, get

I'm new in node.js and I want to call get API. The situation is, I have a edit button and on that click I want to call API.

For that I create a function for call API.

```
function edit(id){                
    window.location.replace('/p/edit?id='+id);
}
```

And in backend I have set API as this.

```
router.get('/edit/:id' , function(req , res , next){ 
   console.log("API calling...");                    
});
```

In `app.js` file ,

```
app.use('/p' , require('./routes/test'));
```

Comment: are you using express ?

Comment: Yes I'm using express and In CMD I got message  `GET /bill/edit?id=1 404 31.480 ms - 786`

Comment: To get a URL parameter's value, use req.params

app.get('/p/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send("tagId is set to " + req.params.id);
});

Comment: I want to set `edit?id=1` in url so that's why I'm using `edit/:id`

Comment: When I call API using postman, In response I got stack trace as this.`<h1>Not Found</h1>
<h2>404</h2>
<pre>Error: Not Found
    at E:\gautum\app.js:30:13`

Comment: do you have app.use('/bill', router);  ?

Comment: yes just to avoid `bill` I set `p` for me `p' is `bill`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
window.location.replace('/bill/edit/id='+id);
```

This is works for me. I hope it may also help you.